# logical empty value in R

Tags: r

After this expression

```
good.rows<-ifelse(nchar(ufo$DateOccurred)!=10 | nchar(ufo$DateReported)!=10, 
FALSE, TRUE)
```

I expected to get vectors of Booleans but I got

```
length(good.rows)
```

[1] 0

This is logical(empty) as I can see in R studio. What can I do to solve this?

dput(head(ufo))

```
"structure(list(DateOccured = structure(c(9412, 9413, 9131, 9260, 
9292, 9428), class = "Date"), DateReported = structure(c(9412, 
9414, 9133, 9260, 9295, 9427), class = "Date"), Location = c(" Iowa City, IA", 
" Milwaukee, WI", " Shelton, WA", " Columbia, MO", " Seattle, WA", 
" Brunswick County, ND"), ShortDescription = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), Duration = c(NA, "2 min.", NA, "2 min.", NA, "30 min."), LongDescription = c("Man repts. witnessing &quot;flash, followed by a classic UFO, w/ a tailfin at back.&quot; Red color on top half of tailfin. Became triangular.", 
"Man  on Hwy 43 SW of Milwaukee sees large, bright blue light streak by his car, descend, turn, cross road ahead, strobe. Bizarre!", 
"Telephoned Report:CA woman visiting daughter witness discs and triangular ships over Squaxin Island in Puget Sound. Dramatic.  Written report, with illustrations, submitted to NUFORC.", 
"Man repts. son&apos;s bizarre sighting of small humanoid creature in back yard.  Reptd. in Acteon Journal, St. Louis UFO newsletter.", 
"Anonymous caller repts. sighting 4 ufo&apos;s in NNE sky, 45 deg. above horizon.  (No other facts reptd.  No return tel. #.)", 
"Sheriff&apos;s office calls to rept. that deputy, 20 mi. SSE of Wilmington,  is looking at peculiar, bright white, strobing light."
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")"
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(ufo)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(ufo, 20))`.

Comment: Check `ufo$DateOccurred` and `ufo$DateReported`. I think at least one of these is `NULL` (doesn't exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why this could be happening:

- You're dataset is empty, check this using the dim() method.
- The columns are not of type Character check this using the class() 
  method.
- If both of these are correct try running the nchar(...)    statements
  separately.

Below I've create an example that works correctly, where I've gone through the above mentioned steps. In future please provide a reproducible example as part of your question.

```
# Create sample data
ufo <- data.frame(DateOccurred=c("a","bb","ccc"), 
                  DateReported=c("a","bb","ccc"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
print(ufo)

# Check size of data (make sure data has rows and columns are of type Character)
dim(ufo)
class(ufo$DateOccurred)
class(ufo$DateReported)

# Check nchar statements (Should run without error/warnings)
nchar(ufo$DateOccurred)
nchar(ufo$DateReported)

# Actual 
good.rows <- ifelse(nchar(ufo$DateOccurred)!=3 | nchar(ufo$DateReported)!=3,
                    FALSE, TRUE)
print(good.rows)
length(good.rows)
```